# Realtime updates with Firestore after migration from Realtimedatabase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently migrating my application from Realtimedatabase to Firestore. I am stuck with a issue in which i need your suggestions.

The application is for a energy monitoring system where minute by minute data is passed from a client device. This is then to be read by web app which is in a different place. The client is in Python and the server is an web application.

My data structure is as follows

```
Energmeter1
    --->PowerData
       -->Auto-ID1
           -->Volt:315
           -->timeint: 365789    
       -->Auto-ID2
           -->Volt:318
           -->timeint: 365790
```

Now at the receiving end in the web app I have a charting application that updates as each data is added.

With Firebase Realtime it was very easy and seamless i used the below code

```
var fb = firebase.database().ref(url);
fb.endAt().limitToLast(3).on('child_added', function(data)
```

whenever a new entry was made I use to receive and display it on the realtime dashboard but with firestore it seems impossible

```
feeder1
.orderBy("timeint") 
.onSnapshot(function(doc)
```

The above function retrieves all record in the queries not just the one that was recently added.

My questions,

1. Is my approach right ?
2. Can we implement a similar functionality with Firestore or it is not possible at all ?

If you need more details please let me know I will be happy to provide

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The **snapshot** contains all documents that match the query. But you can easily find only the new additions by checking the `docChanges` property. From the [Firestore documentation on checking changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots):

> ```
> db.collection("cities").where("state", "==", "CA")
>     .onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
>         snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change) {
>             if (change.type === "added") {
>                 console.log("New city: ", change.doc.data());
>             }
>             if (change.type === "modified") {
>                 console.log("Modified city: ", change.doc.data());
>             }
>             if (change.type === "removed") {
>                 console.log("Removed city: ", change.doc.data());
>             }
>         });
>     });
> ```

So in your case:

```
feeder1
  .orderBy("timeint") 
  .onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.docChanges.forEach(function(change) {
      if (change.type === "added") {
        // Do whatever you'd do on on('child_added' on the Realtime Database
      }
    });
  });
```